# TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'related')

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js

I am trying to follow a tutorial from someone who created a full website using Adonisjs, almost everything was exactly like showed in the tutorial, exept that the frontend was a little different, but the results were the same.
Now I am trying to get the posts showed in the browser, but when I try I get this error:
TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'related')
I tried to see if I had mistaken something, but even using the same code used on the tutorial. The error is the same. Here is my code:

```
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'
import State from 'App/Enums/States'
import Post from 'App/Models/Post'
import PostStoreValidator from 'App/Validators/PostStoreValidator'

export default class PostsController {
  public async index({ view, auth, params }: HttpContextContract) {
    const page = params.page ?? 1
    const posts = auth.user!.related('posts').query().paginate(page, 20)
    return view.render('studio/posts/index', { posts })
  }

  public async create({ view }: HttpContextContract) {
    return view.render('studio/posts/create', {})
  }

  public async store({ request, response }: HttpContextContract) {
    const data = await request.validate(PostStoreValidator)

    await Post.create({ stateId: State.PUBLIC, ...data })

    return response.redirect().toRoute('studio.posts.index')
  }
}
```

But there are a lot more, so I am letting my [gthub repositore](https://github.com/GlaudistonNeto/adonisjs-complete-web-application) here, so you can take a look at the entire code. The error shows some typeerror, but I have already tried to copy and paste the same code as gave on the tutorial, but nothing changes...

I hope someone can see what can be causing this error because obviously I can't.

Comment: Why did you place the `!` in `auth.user!`? That's TypeScript telling you that the property is (or may be) `undefined`, and you chose to ignore it.

Comment: I just tried to follow the tutorial. I am still learning Adonisjs, the tutorial uses that exclamation and the code works perfectly, and if I remove the exclamation the error keeps the same way

Comment: Has the tutorial explained how the code ought to work? Did you do any debugging on why `auth.user` is undefined? Or have you only copy-pasted the code?

Comment: That's the tutorial I'm following: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/migrations
Sometimes is just impossible to hear what the guy says because he was doing this in a live 4 months ago, and he speaks to himself sometimes while nobody can properly hear his voice. I followed the first part, and it worked as he showed, but in this second part at minute 58 and on, things stopped working like he shows